# Google sign-in for apps loops

Tags: google-account, google, google-pixel-3-xl

I have several apps that use sign in with google for authentication. Problem is, the sign in screen loops back to select an account after presenting the alllow %app to access these parts of your google account. I hit allow, and it sends me back to account selection instead of signing in.

It's not just one app it's every non-Google app doing it.

Device is a Pixel 3 XL on Android 10.

How do I get it to let me sign in with google in 3rd party apps using google play services? Ones that open a browser to authenticate with google are working fine

Comment: Can you give an example with screenshots? Link those apps from Play Store

Answer (score 0):

It was a temporary failure on Google's side which has since been fixed.